# Google Challenge Dilemma, Insights into possible errors?

Tags: java, python, string, challenge-response

I am currently passing 4 of the 5 hidden test cases for this challenge and would like some input

Quick problem description:

> You are given two input strings, String chunk and String word
>
> The string "word" has been inserted into "chunk" some number of times
>
> The task is to find the shortest string possible when all instances of
>   "word" have been removed from "chunk".
>
> Keep in mind during removal, more instances of the "word" might be
>   created in "chunk". "word" can also be inserted anywhere, including
>   between "word" instances
>
> If there are more the one shortest possible strings after removal,
>   return the shortest word that is lexicographic-ally the earliest.
>
> This is easier understood with examples:
>
> Inputs:
>       (string) chunk = "lololololo"
>       (string) word = "lol"
>
> Output:
>       (string) "looo" (since "looo" is eariler than "oolo")
>
> Inputs:
>       (string) chunk = "goodgooogoogfogoood"
>       (string) word = "goo"
>
> Output:
>       (string) "dogfood"

right now I am iterating forwards then backwards, removing all instances of word and then comparing the two results of the two iterations.

Is there a case I am overlooking? Is it possible there is a case where you have to remove from the middle first or something along those lines?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using? You use both tags java and python.

Comment: I am currently using java. Not sure why I added that tag lol. I'm more interested in reasoning about the potential test cases I could be failing and not a specific implementation though.

Comment: I _suspect_ that there may be some strings that won't succumb to your algorithm, and if you aren't passing all the test cases then it's worthwhile investigating a more thorough search process. FWIW, I can do a complete recursive search in Python in 8 lines that generates all possible reduced strings, plus one more line to get the required minimal string. BTW, if you have some more test data, I wouldn't mind seeing it. :)

Comment: PS. Make sure your code handles cases like `chunk="llolol"; word="lol"` properly.

Comment: I just tested chunk="llolol"; word="lol" and it returned the empty string. BTW I'm using a stack to keep track of word nesting, I just cant find any two strings that break my code and ive been at it for a couple days now.

Comment: How do you access this site?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But i will avoid matching first and last character of chunk. Should replace all other.